# Prove that there is a unique real number $\mu\in (a,b)$ such that $\int_a^bf(t)dt=(\mu-a)c+(b-\mu)d.$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Question: Let $a,c$ be nonnegative real numbers and let $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ be a bijective increasing function. Prove that there is a unique real number $\mu\in (a,b)$ such that $$\int_a^bf(t)dt=(\mu-a)c+(b-\mu)d.$$

Solution: Note that since $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ is bijective and increasing implies that $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$. Thus, if we can show that there is a unique real number $\mu\in (a,b)$ such that $$\int_a^bf(t)dt=(\mu-a)f(a)+(b-\mu)f(b),$$ we will be done. Now by MVT we can conclude that there exists $\theta \in(a,b)$ such that $$(b-a)f(\theta)=\int_a^bf(t)dt.$$ Next let $h:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $$h(x)=(b-a)f(\theta)-(x-a)f(a)-(b-x)f(b).$$ Note that $h$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and we have $h(a)=(b-a)(f(\theta)-f(b))<0 \hspace{0.2 cm} (\because f(\theta)<f(b))$ and $h(b)=(b-a)(f(\theta)-f(a))<0 \hspace{0.2 cm} (\because f(\theta)>f(a)).$ Therefore, by IVT we can conclude that there exists $\mu\in(a,b)$ such that $h(\mu)=0$, that is $$\int_a^bf(t)dt=(\mu-a)c+(b-\mu)d.$$

Let us now assume that $h(\mu_1)=h(\mu_2)=0$ for some $\mu_1,\mu_2\in(a,b)$. Doing some algebraic manipulations would imply that $(\mu_1-\mu_2)(f(a)-f(b))=0$. Note that $f(a)\neq f(b)$, which leads us to $\mu_1=\mu_2$.

Thus, we can conclude that $\mu$ is unique.

Is this solution correct and is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: This looks sensible to me overall; another approach is to simply solve the original equation for $\mu$; since it's linear, this will give a formula for $\mu$ in terms of $a, b, f(a), f(b)$ and the integral. Then you should be able to show that the value must be in $(a,b)$.

Comment: Also, [second mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Second_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals). For uniqueness, note that the right hand side $bd - ac - \mu(d-c)$ is strictly decreasing as a function of $\mu$.

Answer (score 1):

The following may be simpler to write, is but the same story. Let $h:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be the linear, strictly decreasing function:
$$
h(x) = (b-x)d + (x-a)c -\int_a^bf(t)\; dt\ .
$$
Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
h(a) &= (b-a)d -\int_a^bf(t)\; dt \ >\  (b-a)d -\int_a^b d\; dt =0\ ,\\  
h(b) &= (b-a)c -\int_a^bf(t)\; dt \ <\  (b-a)c -\int_a^b c\; dt =0\ ,  
\end{aligned}
$$
where for the strict inequalities we need less than bijectivity. We find an intermediate $\mu$ with $h(\mu)=0$, in fact we have have an explicit formula, the one  from the OP taken as starting point.